# Alphabetic order of an array of a Class

Tags: java, sorting, java-7, bubble-sort

I have an array of Class `Customer`. I would like to alphabetically re-order the elements in the array of Class `Customer` based on a field called `name`.

Here is the code I am using:

```
int j;
        boolean flag = true;  // will determine when the sort is finished
        Customer temp;
        while ( flag )
        {
            flag = false;
            for ( j = 0;  j < count_customers;  j++ )
            {

                if ( customers[ j ].getName().toString().compareToIgnoreCase( customers[ j + 1 ].getName().toString() ) > 0 )
                {
                    temp = customers[ j ];
                    customers[ j ] = customers[ j+1 ];     // swapping
                    customers[ j+1 ] = temp; 
                    flag = true;
                 } 
             } 
         }
```

`customers[]` is the array that holds `Customer`
`count_customers` represents the number of active customers.
for some reason when I run the code below returns nothing:

```
        for(int i=0; i < count_customers; i++)
        {
            tmp_results += customers[ i ].toString() + "\n";
        }
```

`.toString()` is defined in `Customer` class, it just prints everything about the customer out.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you set the value of count_customers?

Comment: `count_customers` is working, I just simply run `count_customers++` when a new customer is added

Comment: (Unrelated, but consider giving your flag a meaningful name.)

Comment: @Alya'aGamal I cant just print customers[i], thats an object, not a string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new class `CustomerComparator` and sort your `Customer[]` using `Arrays.sort(array, new CustomerComparator());`

```
public class CustomerComparator implements Comparator<Customer> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {
        return c1.getName().compareTo(c2.getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: Or if you can't change Customer, create a Comparator for it.

Comment: I cant edit Customer, how can I create a comparator? could you explain please?